# Presence of Identity Element and abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I.N.Herstein in Topics of Algebra defines a group as a set having a special element $i$ such that:

$a,i\in A(S) $ which satisfies $i\cdot a = a\cdot i = a$

In this way, this follows commutativity holds true for identity element, then doesnt it run contradictory to the non-necessary condition that $a \cdot b \neq b \cdot a$ ?

In similar vein is the set of integers under subtraction a group? {my reasoning is no it isnt, because $a-0 = a \neq 0-a$}

Soham

Comment: That is not what a group is, and I doubt Herstein has made such an error. Read his definition again, in full.

Comment: @ChrisEagle This is **one** of the properties of a group. I believe the OP skipped the other three since they are not related to his question.

Comment: @Code-Guru Indeed perhaps I had been vague, and gave off an impression that it is the only property, but it is one of the four necessary properties. I left those off because they are not pertinent.

Comment: Just because a condition is "non-necessary" doesn't mean it *can't* hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-necessary condition is $\forall a,b \in A, a \cdot b \not= b \cdot a$. This doesn't rule out that it may be true for **some** $a, b \in A$. In fact, it could be true for all elements in the group. Then we call it an Abelian group, which is still a group, nonetheless.

And you are correct, the integers (or rationals or real numbers) with subtraction does not form a group. You gave one reason. You could also check associativity.

Comment: Yes, thanks I checked all the 4, and indeed it fails.

Answer (score 6):

The commutativity of the identity in a group is part of its definition, even in a non-commutative group.  And you are correct about subtraction not being a valid group operator: it's not even associative.

Answer (score 4):

Non-commutative denotes the negation of the commutative law $$\rm\:\color{#C00} \lnot\ [\color{#C00}\forall\,x,y\!:\ xy \color{#C00}= yx]\, \equiv\, \color{#C00}\exists\,x,y\!:\ xy\color{#C00}\ne yx\:$$  In words, commutativity fails to be true universally (for all elements), precisely when there exists at least one counterexample. It doesn't mean that commutativity *always* fails.

Comment: @Soham Because confusion of quantifiers is a common problem when learning mathematics, it sometimes helps to *mathematically* "reify" the quantifiers, so that one may learn to *rigorously* manipulate them *algebraically* (vs. intuitively, in natural language). One needs to learn to symbolically translate  *logical* word problems" just as one does for *algebra* word problems. And, in fact, logic can be completely algebraicized (cf work of Tarski, Henkin, Halmos, et al).

Comment: @BillDubuque : What does the first symbol that u have used mean ?

Comment: @Theorem The first symbol $\:\lnot\:$ denotes logical negation. For the others see the Wikipedia articles on $\:\forall = $ [Universal Quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification)   and  $\:\exists = $ [Existential Quantification.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification)

Answer (score 1):

The "unnecessary condition" is that $a\cdot b= b \cdot a $ for *all* $a,b$. We don't need this fact to prove that the identity commutes. Let's assume there are two: an *left* identity $i$ and a *right* identity $j$.

We find that $i\cdot j=i=j$, since we can use the definition of either identity. So *they're actually the same*. In the immortal words of highlander, "there can be only one". So the same identity element has to work for both sides if it's going to work at all.